# group Policy: Do not allow users to delete files and folders but he can create, modify, rename file and folder

Tags: windows-server-2012

group Policy: Do not allow users to delete files and folders but he can create, modify, rename file and folder (tell in windows 2012 server R2).

Comment: A group policy, no, a file permission, yes.  If the user is an admin that can be overridden though

Comment: You're asking for a world of problem with such NTFS ACL security configurations. Maybe not for your specific requirement though but we'll see what the future tells... Setting an explicit `DENY` for a common security group would likely work out well. Be sure to test, etc. but here's an answer that may help give you a potential starting point: https://superuser.com/questions/868399/how-to-make-a-folder-read-only-in-windows/1224275#1224275

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *Delete* permission from the files **and** the *Delete Files and Subfolders* permission from the folder.

You can do this with the Security tab in a file or folder's Properties window or with the `icacls` command-line utility.