# Can't deny 'change' permissions on drive without also denying read permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to allow Read permissions but deny Write permissions on this storage drive, but I seemingly can't, using the permissions dialogue. How do I go about this? Running Windows Server 2012 R2.

[image]

Comment: I believe Everyone includes CreatorOwner, and just about all groups, so any deny on it is inadvisable. There is almost always a better way to handle things than a Deny, and the larger the construct you deny on (in this case not a group, but a metagroup) the less its a good idea. perhaps this is what you want: https://superuser.com/questions/868399/how-to-make-a-folder-read-only-in-windows

Comment: If you haven’t allowed change permissions then it is already implicitly denied. You can’t deny something they don’t have. Lesser permissions are always included in the greater permissions. Also you are using share permissions which is almost never used. Instead you should be using the more flexible NTFS permissions under the security tab. You are violating best practices in two ways. Using share permissions and using denies.